# How to dispatch an async job in Laravel 5.8 with Redis?

Tags: laravel, redis, delayed-job

I need to run a very time consuming task asynchronous in Laravel 5.8. This is the `.env` file

```
...
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
...
```

The queue driver must be Redis because the website uses `Laravel-Echo` with `redis` and `socket.io` to broadcast messages and I can't change queue driver to `database`.

This is the job I created

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class BroadcastRepeatJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        sleep(30);
    }
}
```

and this is the `HomeController`:

```
public function index()
{
    BroadcastRepeatJob::dispatch()->onQueue("default");
    dd(1);
    ...
}
```

and I also run the following artisan commands

```
php artisan queue:work
php artisan queue:listen
```

when I visit `/index` of `HomeController` I expect to see `dd(1)` immediately not after `30` seconds because the `sleep(30)` must be ran in a queue but this does not happen and I have to wait 30 seconds to see `dd(1)`. How can I run the job in background asynchronous ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching your `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `redis` rather than `sync`

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the connection information for each server that
    | is used by your application. A default configuration has been added
    | for each back-end shipped with Laravel. You are free to add more.
    |
    | Drivers: "sync", "database", "beanstalkd", "sqs", "redis", "null"
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver'        => 'database',
            'table'         => 'jobs',
            'queue'         => 'default',
            'retry_after'   => 90,
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver'        => 'redis',
            'connection'    => 'default',
            'queue'         => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after'   => 90,
            'block_for'     => null,
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From `.env` I changed the connection to `redis`. I changed the `handle` function of job and wrote `Log::info('From Broadcast job');`. After running the code, no log is reported and I just see the `dd(1)`. To make sure that the handle function is called, I added a syntax error there, The laravel reported that error, hence Im sure it is called but it doesn't add the Log to the log files.

Comment: @MamaD you also need to start queue workers to process the queue if you are not using sync. Please see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker). You can also check out [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon) which is an excellent package for managing your queue workers.